# Default type of XML element without dtd/xsd

Tags: xml, types, xsd, dtd

I've to implement a XML processor that contains some large preformatted text nodes.
Years ago I had some problems with msxml(4-6), storing preformatted texts, without loosing the whitespace. 
Now we figured out, that a xs:string defaults to

```
<xs:whiteSpace value="preserve" id="string.preserve"/>
```

Assuming a XML without DTD or XSD

```
<myXML>
  <myNode>Some text with    whitespace</myNode>
  <myNumber>123</myNumber>
</myXML>
```

To which type do XML elements default, if there is nothing declared ?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no model (DTD or XSD) then the XML processor parses all values as 'parsed character data' (i.e. a string of characters).